# Unsupported Architecture(s): cputype(12) cpusubtype(9)

Tags: trigger.io

I am attempting to upload my Trigger.io built iOS application to the App Store via the Application Loader. I am getting the error: "iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable contains unsupported architecture(s): cputype (12) cpusubtype (9)".

I am building on Window 7 64bit. Forge tools running at version 3.3.34. Trigger.io platform_version: 1.4 .

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What version of iOS is your device running, and what is the device?

Comment: Would the device have anything to do with this error? This error is coming from the Application Loader, not something on the device.

Answer (score 1):

I had an older version of XCode on my Mac (3.X vintage), and the Application Loader that was coming up was from that version! I have since uninstalled the old XCode, and I am now using the new version of Application Loader. This error has gone away.